# Probability of Picking marbles - Generalization

Tags: probability

Supposed I have m marbles, with n red and m-n blue. I randomly pick k marbles from the set. I know that the probability to have at least one red is 1 - Ck_m-n/Ck_m, but what's the probability to have at least 2 red marbles? Or at least q red marbles (q < k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P\left(R\geq q\right)=1-\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}P\left(R=r\right)=1-\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\binom{n}{r}\binom{m-n}{k-r}\binom{m}{k}^{-1}$$

Also $$P\left(R\geq q\right)=\sum_{r=q}^{k}P\left(R=r\right)=\sum_{r=q}^{k}\binom{n}{r}\binom{m-n}{k-r}\binom{m}{k}^{-1}$$

For efficient calculation choose the one that has less terms.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough reputation to vote up but this is the correct answer. Marked as resolved.